# Passed value mismatch error for SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween()

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to calculate distance between two points using  SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween. The value which I provided is from **com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng** but the required type is **com.google.android.libraries.maps.model.LatLng**

How do I resolve this?

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils-v3:2.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
```

```
LatLng userAddress = new LatLng(currentRiderLocation.getLatitude(), currentRiderLocation.getLongitude());
LatLng destinationAddress = new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude());

 double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(userAddress,destinationAddress);
```

Error
`'computeDistanceBetween(com.google.android.libraries.maps.model.LatLng, com.google.android.libraries.maps.model.LatLng)' in 'com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil' cannot be applied to '(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng, com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)'`